# Formalizing with Induction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

In this thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113083/exponential-blow-up-of-dnf-to-cnf-2n-terms), it makes sense why there is exponential blow up because of the conversion. My question is how would we use induction to prove this? I've started, but I'm getting mixed up with the inductive step.

We start off with the base case being n=2, we have 4 terms, $P,Q,R,S$. As a result of distribution, we generate $((P \lor Q) \land R) \lor (P \lor Q) \land S)$, and this leads to $(P \lor R) \land (Q \lor R) \land (P \lor S) \land (Q \lor S)$, so $2^2 = 4$ clauses. For the inductive hypothesis, we assume that for $n=k$, we will have $2^k$ clauses. Can anyone show how we would do the inductive step?

I get stuck here. Say we have $n=k+1$ terms, then what we end up getting is $2^1 \times 2^k = 2^{k+1}$ clauses, but I can't generate the reasoning behind it. Can anyone help me reason with this step? Thanks.

Comment: "I can't generate the reasoning behind it". Can you start by writing the statement to prove in mathematical language, preferably with symbols? I think that helps with going in the right direction.

Comment: @GitGud can we start with the idea that $2^{n+1}$ introduces two new terms to a formula of length $2n$, as $(P_{2n+1} \lor P_{2n+2})$? From there would we be able to infer something about the distributivity from the base case? This makes me feel like my base case is messed up, I feel like it should be when $n=1$?

Comment: The way you're phrasing things makes me suspect that you don't know how to write your thesis a little bit more formally. Not being able to do this is getting in your way. I insist that you start by writing the statement to prove.